# Android for-loop getting stuck in endless loop

Tags: android

I have a JSONArray of JSONObjects in each of which is a string with the key "kind". I'm trying to loop through the JSONarray and organize them by "kind" to use to fill a SeperatedListAdapter. what I am trying to achieve is this structure

```
{
   communications[
       { "header":"kind"
          communications[
             {}
             {}
             {}
             {}
          ]

        }

       { "header":"kind"
          communications[
             {}
             {}
             {}
             {}
          ]

        }

   ]


}
```

The problem I'm having is the for loop i have created to achieve this gets stuck in an endless loop and thus crashes the application. Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

Here's my code I know it gets stuck in a loop as it runs the log "1" about 1000 times even though I know there's only 5 things in the array I'm passing in.

```
for(int i = 0; i < communicationsFromFile.length(); i++){
                JSONObject communication = communicationsFromFile.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.v("Communications", "kind = " + communication.getString("kind"));
                Log.v("Communications", "newComArray = " + newComArray);
                if(newComArray.length() != 0){
                    Log.v("Communications", "newComArray IsNotempty");

                    for(int a = 0; a < newComArray.length();a++){
                        JSONObject itemInArray = newComArray.getJSONObject(a);
                        JSONArray communicationsForKind = itemInArray.getJSONArray("communications"); 

                        Log.v("Communications", "1");

                        if(itemInArray.getString("header").equals(communication.getString("kind"))){
                            Log.v("Communications", "Header Exists");
                            communicationsForKind.put(communication);
                            itemInArray.put("communications", communicationsForKind);
                            newComArray.put(itemInArray);


                        }else{
                            Log.v("Communications", "Header Does not Exist");
                            JSONObject addItemInArray = new JSONObject();
                            JSONArray addArrayToItem = new JSONArray();
                            addArrayToItem.put(communication);
                            addItemInArray.put("header", communication.getString("kind"));
                            addItemInArray.put("communications", addArrayToItem);

                            newComArray.put(addItemInArray);
                        }

                    }

                }else{

                    JSONObject addItemInArray = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray addArrayToItem = new JSONArray();
                    addArrayToItem.put(communication);
                    addItemInArray.put("header", communication.getString("kind"));
                    addItemInArray.put("communications", addArrayToItem);
                    newComArray.put(addItemInArray);    

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the inner for loop, you put new objects in the `newComArray`. The condition `a < newComArray.length()` is always satisfied because `a` and the array length both grow at the same rate.

Comment: thanks for your help can you explain abit more i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: I figured it out i changed neComArray to the orignal array